# How to dispose object from another class

Tags: java, multithreading

I’m not sure if it’s actually  possible , but let’s assume I have two classes. One run endless loop inside *Thread* , another create instance of that class inside method **main**. So everything works well , but how can I dispose that instance in **main** and interrupt from executing Thread with endless loop.
Here is an example:

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  new ThreadClass();
{
public class ThreadClass{
 public ThreadClass{
  try{
   Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    int i = 0;
    public void run(){
     while(true){
      i += 1;
      System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  });
  t.start();
  }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("something ");
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That code won't compile. When asking for help, providing code that actually compiles is usually important. (Properly formatting it is useful, too -- remember, you're asking other people to spend their time helping you.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry , I wrote all this code manually using mobile app , I might’ve  missed something , but initially  I checked weather it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThreadClass` has to expose a way (e.g., a method) to tell the loop to terminate. (Typically that involves setting/clearing a `volatile` flag that the loop uses in its `while`.) Then `main` would use that method at...some appropriate time. It's not clear what time you'd want it to, but you'd keep a reference to the instance you created and when that time came, you'd use the method.

Comment: That works , thank you. But what alternative for the same case , but without Thread, just while loop, how can I stop it from another class , is volatile suitable for it, or there something else ?

Comment: @GipsyKing - If it's not running on another thread, no other code can run, so the only way to stop the loop is from the code in the loop.